# Pass value once Popover table view is dismissed in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have a storyboard like below:

[image: My StoryBoard]

The second view will be shown as popover when the first field (Select Form) is clicked.I have a set of values as table cells in the popover tableview.
So when I click any cell in tableview I need that value in the second textbox(NewFormName) once the popover is disabled.

**I am getting value in MainViewController. But not able to use it to change the textbox value.**

here is my popover didselectanyrow code:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var dict = FormList[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    let formname:String = dict.form_name!;

    /*created an instance called 
   'MainViewControllerInstance' of MainViewController earlier*/

    MainViewControllerInstance.SecondTextBox.text = formname
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This shows an error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any solution? I need the selected value of popover tablecell to the second text box once the popver is dismissed.

Comment: use closure as a variable and get value

Comment: i think you shouldn't assume that dict.form_name is not nil.

Comment: you can not `MainViewControllerInstance.SecondTextBox.text ` pass value directly take variable in SecondVC and assign it

Comment: Try checking if FormList itself is nil.

Comment: Value is actually NOT Nil.. I am able to print the value in Console in main view controller. But not able to use it in TextBox.text

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint  Can you explain this. I didn't get this. I tried many variations on the same thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `PopoverViewController`:

```
var delegate: MainViewController?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var dict = FormList[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    let formname: String? = dict.form_name
    delegate?.updateTextBox(with: formname)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

In your `MainViewController`:

```
func updateTextBox(with string: String?) {
    if string != nil {
        self.SecondTextBox.text = string!
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
            let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PopoverViewController
            popoverViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

Comment: Enjoy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

use a delegate or closure to pass the value back to the last object

Comment: Did you mean to use like this?
I decalred like this,
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! MainViewController

and used like: 
    delegate.textBox.text = "My Text"

But didn't work. Thread/ Error